# How to check array?

Tags: javascript

I have a code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var inputList = [];

input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
        inputList.push(input.files);
    }
});

for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
    console.log(inputList[i]);
}
```

From the input tag, I select multiple files from my pc and save them to the inputList array
At the web console: I use the inputList[] command to check each array element and see the results, ie the array received files.
Then I use the for loop to check the array, but I don't see the results in the console window.

How to iterate through this array? (cannot continue other work if cannot access array)
Hope you guys can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: move the second for loop inside the eventlistener.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `inputList.push(input.files[i])` ?

Comment: It looks like you're checking the array *before* the user has the change to fill it.

Comment: Hi eamanola, I want to check outside the eventlistener

Comment: _"I want to check outside the eventlistener"_ - okay, but _when_? The array only gets filled when the change handler for the input has fired - so doing it _before_ that, makes little sense.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, but how can I do it later?

Answer (score 0):

You push the for Example the fileNames to a global array. Then you want to check which files these array contains. Then you must trigger a function which iterate the global array. Like this:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var inputList = [];

input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {  
  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
    inputList.push(input.files[i].name);
  }
});

function check() { 
  console.log(inputList);
  for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
    console.log('list',inputList[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input" multiple>
<button onclick="check()">check</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Maik Lowrey. This means I must trigger "a function that iterates over the global array", every time I want to work with this array.

Comment: @Diana you welcome :-)! Yes that is correct.